# Diferencias y ventajas: Set y Map contra Array y Object

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Leyendo sobre ES6 y sus características, me surge la duda sobre:

1. ¿Cuál es la ventaja de *Map* frente un *Object*?
2. ¿Cuál es la ventaja de *Set* frente un *Array*?

Entiendo que ambas son para colecciones de datos, pero ¿por qué no usar los datos primitivos en su lugar?

Referencias (teóricas) que he consultado:

- [Set | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Set).
- [Map | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Map).
- [EcmaScript 6; New Features](http://es6-features.org/).
- [ECMAScript® 2018 Language Specification](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/).

Comment: ¿Has investigado algo? ¿Has comparado por ti mismo?

Comment: @A.Cedano sí, he añadido las referencias de consulta, sería bueno algo de paráfrasis y casos practicos.

Comment: la pregunta que te debes hacer que es diferente, contra que lo comparas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cito las mismas fuentes que proporcionaste:

[Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Set#Descripci%C3%B3n) vs Array:

Los objetos Set son colecciones de valores. Se puede iterar sus elementos en el orden de su inserción. **Un valor en un Set sólo puede estar una vez**; éste es único en la colección Set.

Visto con un ejemplo:

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3];
var set = new Set(arr);
console.log(set); // {1,2,3}


var arr = [1, 2, 1];
var set = new Set(arr);
console.log(set); // {1,2}
```

[Map vs Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Map#Objetos_y_mapas_comparados)

Los Objetos son similares a los Maps en cuanto a que ambos permiten establecer claves a valores, recuperar dichos valores, eliminar claves, y detectar si existe algo almacenado en una clave determinada. Por esto, los Objects han sido usados históricamente como Maps; no obstante, hay diferencias importantes entre  Objects y Maps que hacen mejor usar un  Map  en la mayoría de casos

- Las claves de un `Object` son `Strings` y `Symbols`, mientras que para un `Map` pueden ser de cualquier tipo, incluyendo funciones, objetos y cualquier otro tipo primitivo.
  Puedes saber facilmente el tamaño de un Map usando la propiedad size, mientras que le número de propiedades en un Object tiene que ser deternminado manualmente.
- Un `Map` es un `iterable` lo que permite iterar directamente sobre el, mientras que si queremos iterar sobre un `Object` necesitamos obtener primero las claves de alguna forma para después iterar sobre el.
- Un `Object` tiene prototipo, por lo que hay claves por defecto en tu mapa que pueden colisionar con tus claves si no eres cuidadoso. En el estandard ES5 esto se puede evitar usando `mapa = Object.create(null)`, pero esto raramente se hace.